# Get original filename from File

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file

I have an action that takes in a System.File

```
public bool UploadToServer( File file )
```

And I would like to use the file's original name in the server once it gets there. I have looked in [MSDN's File Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) but don't see anything that looks like I could get the filename or for that matter, the filepath. Is there an attribute I can use from the `File` to get it's original name or should I simply make the signiture look like this:

```
public bool UploadToServer( File file, string fileName )
```

?

## Solution

As @Marko suggested `HttpPostedFile` is what I went with, I did not have `Server.Web` in my resources for that project which was what was tripping me up.

Comment: Exposing the clientside path to the server would be a bit of a security/privacy issue

Comment: I know for sure that firefox anonymises the file path of uploaded files. You should be able to get the filename though. `File` is abstract, so maybe you need the derived type. Try `FileStream` instead.

Comment: The full path is only exposed by people using [ancient web browsers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2009/07/27/uploading-a-file-using-fileupload-control-fails-in-ie8.aspx) so yo will be unable to do this without some weird workaround.

Comment: please refer to this article http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try the code below, this way you do not need to care about the path or any other security issues.

```
[HttpPost]
       public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
       {
           if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
           {
               var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);



               file.SaveAs(path);
           }
        }
```

Comment: Couldn't find the type or namespace, what are you `using` for that?

Comment: HttpPostedFileBase is located in System.Web, in your question tag you specificed Asp.net MVC which version are you using?

Comment: @WayneOlinger you should not use File , but as Marko mentioned, use HttpPostedFileBase, and you can get the file name as he showed you

Comment: @Marko I'm using 4, in another project I have I can use `HttpPostedFileBase` no problem, do i not have the correct references set up?

Comment: @WayneOlinger it would appear you do not, try adding System.Web to project references and see if that solves your problem if not compare this project to the your other project that works and see what is different.

Comment: @Marko I will do just that, thanks for the help. If that can't be figured out I think I might use the commented suggestion of just using a `FileStream`