# file name scrubbing on the client side vs server side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

When uploading files from many separate web pages and controllers, my C# backend breaks when a file with an HTML entity in the name gets uploaded:

```
An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A potentially dangerous Request.Files value was detected from the client (filename="...for_files_&#x23;US2023103...").
```

Notice the HTML entity `&#x23;` in the name, which should just be `#`. I could go through every web page's JS and force the JS to change/decode the HTML entities on the client side (lots of little changes) or I could change the server side code to handle this, but I'm not sure the server side method could be done without exposing the server to vulnerabilities.

To prevent this from being an opinionated question, I explicitly ask:

**Is there any way to escape/validate file names on the server side, without throwing an exception, and without exposing the server to vulnerabilities?**

Here is the code I am trying to use for replacing the filename:

```
        if (requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Files)
            {
                file.FileName = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(file.FileName);
            }
        }
```

This of course is not allowed because FileName is a readonly property of `HttpPostedFileBase`. I am thinking that it may be smart to check the filename, if it has HTML entities, or semicolons, then instantiate a new HttpPostedFileBase object with the corrected name.

Comment: Please show us the code that throws the exception

Comment: Just going off the thread title, you should always perform data sanitation on the server side, even if you do or do not have it on the client.  You cannot trust the client to do what you expect it to do.  The server is the last line of defense before the data is stored or published to that user, or another.

Comment: @JacobIRR Wndrr's answer solve your problem ? Feel free to accept his answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know which .net framework you use but but you can try making use of the [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Note about security: sanitisation/validation **MUST** be made on the server side. Client side is **ONLY** for user experience. Nothing that you do on the client side is really secure since you have no way to ensure it was actually done without re-doing it on the server (that was my rant about the title)

You can try that

```
if (requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Files.Count > 0)
{
    var finalDir = "path/to/dir"
    foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Files)
    {
        var decodedFileName = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(file.FileName);

        try
        {
            // Will not overwrite if the destination file already exists.
            if(filename.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) >= 0)
                throw new Exception('invalid name');
            else
                File.Copy(decodedFileName , Path.Combine(finalDir, Guid.NewGuid()));
        }

        // Catch exception if the file was already copied.
        catch (IOException copyError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(copyError.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

or even easier, as per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31543902/6838730)

```
if (requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Files.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in requestContext.HttpCont
    {
        file.SaveAs(Path.Combine("destination/path/", Guid.NewGuid());
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the OP with some code I am trying on the server side when the request first gets kicked off.

Comment: Why do you need to update the file's name property ? Just save the decoded file name in an other var and copy the file using this name ?

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know if it helps or not :-)

Comment: You might also check that the filename is valid for windows filename.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()).

Comment: I updated my answer with what I believe is a correct use of your your suggestion @Fran please check it and let me know if I misunderstood how it should be used. I had never heard of this.

Comment: @GGO I didn't ask the question.  I was telling Wndrr that he could also add another check.